# Excel Solver ends before finding a solution - VBA

Tags: vba, excel, solver

I'm a starter user of VBA and I'm having some problem with Excel Solver.

Basically I have to calculate the Fair Values of several financial instruments, grouped by the country of origins.

For each country the solver will minimize a function in order to find the model parameters.

So far I've been able to make it work and among 50 different countries/category the solver works in 49 cases.

Here comes my problem, when it comes to this country the solvers steps out after 3 or 4 iterations. leaving the objective funciont far from been minimized.
But when I click on a commandbutton linked exactly to the same subroutine it finds a solution.

Here is part of my code, NSCoeff is the sub linked to the solver.

```
Sub NelsonSiegel()
Dim a, b, c, d, e, f, g, p, s, I, t, v, pv, TIR As Variant
Dim NumBonds, bnd_cnt As Integer
Dim current_wb As String
Dim spot(), df, dfcf, NumberCashFlows, Lambda, Lambda2, Beta1, Beta2, Beta3, Beta4, TimeToCashFlow(), NSPV As Variant
Dim j As Integer
Dim Time() As Variant
Dim A1() As Variant
Dim A2() As Variant
Dim A3() As Variant
Dim A4() As Variant
current_wb = ThisWorkbook.Name
NumBonds = Sheets("bonds").Cells(1, 7).Value

Workbooks(current_wb).Sheets("Nelson_Siegel").Range("n4:s4").Value = 1
NSCoeff
Workbooks(current_wb).Sheets("bonds").Calculate 'download coupon date for NS procedure

Lambda = Worksheets("model").Cells(28, 2)
Beta1 = Worksheets("model").Cells(29, 2)
Beta2 = Worksheets("model").Cells(30, 2)
Beta3 = Worksheets("model").Cells(31, 2)
Beta4 = Worksheets("model").Cells(32, 2)
Lambda2 = Worksheets("model").Cells(33, 2)
```

and here the NSCoeff sub

```
Sub NSCoeff()
Dim current_wb As String
current_wb = ThisWorkbook.Name


Workbooks(current_wb).Sheets("Nelson_Siegel").Activate

    SolverOk SetCell:="$N$9", MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$N$4:$S$4", _
        Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$N$4", Relation:=3, FormulaText:="0.001"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$S$4", Relation:=3, FormulaText:="0.001"
    SolverOk SetCell:="$N$9", MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$N$4:$S$4", _
        Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverOk SetCell:="$N$9", MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$N$4:$S$4", _
        Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverSolve userFinish:=True
```

Any Idea on how to solve this problem? The solver doesn't find a solution when is launched from another subroutine but when it's lauched from a commandbutton it works.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

A first step would be to catch the return value from `SolverSolve`.  This would allow you to determine why it ended.

```
Sub NSCoeff()
    Dim current_wb As Workbook
    Dim ret As Integer

    Set current_wb = ThisWorkbook

    current_wb.Sheets("Nelson_Siegel").Activate

    SolverOk SetCell:="$N$9", MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$N$4:$S$4", _
        Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$N$4", Relation:=3, FormulaText:="0.001"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$S$4", Relation:=3, FormulaText:="0.001"
    ret = SolverSolve userFinish:=True
    MsgBox "SolverSolve returned a value of " & ret
End Sub
```

Then you can consult [Microsoft's Website](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff197237.aspx) to determine why the solver decided to exit.

From there, you can use that information to determine how to proceed to.

Comment: That's a good tip, I've tried to catch the value of `SolverSolve` and the value is at the first run ( the one that ends before of the time) is 

0 
Solver found a solution. All constraints and optimality conditions are satisfied.
 
 When I click the `CommandButton` I get 
1 Solver has converged to the current solution. All constraints are satisfied.

I still have no clue of why this is happening, any thoughts?